# Another service JAR is creating Spring's autoconfiguration (Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate')

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mongotemplate

I have one Java spring boot application (call it utility service) and many other Java spring boot applications (call them as clients).

Both (utility service and clients) use Spring's autoconfiguration. When I am trying to put JAR of utility service into a client, after building the client, it is throwing error at `bootrun`. The error is:

```
Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory]: : 
Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: : 
Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: 
Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.bson.io.BasicOutputBuffer.<init>(I)V;
```

I can fix this problem by applying `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})` in the client's `Application.java`.

But I have many such clients and I don't want to modify client's code (except it's `build.gradle`).

Is there any way from utility service to modify and achieve above?

Comment: Your library is bringing in incompatible versions. So you probably have a hardcoded managed Mongo or other dependency version which in turn is wrecking havoc on the other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to exclude the class when you include the dependency in any of your clients. Once you exclude the mongoTemplate configuration class it should not appear in your classpath while building the client service code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can it be possible without doing change in client?

Comment: As you specified in your question, this change is in just `build.gradle` to exclude the particular class from the dependency. This should be easy change.